# ECHO'ing quoted variable from SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server

What alternatives could I use when displaying quotes `"` from my SQL Server database? Something that works like `*_real_escape_string`?

E.g.

`$row['details']` has a value of `"This is my quoted sentence"`

Simply `ECHO`ing this gives:

```
�This is my quoted sentence�
```

And I want it to go like this:

```
"This is my quoted sentence"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the string in question begins and ends with a double quote character (unicode U+0022) and not left and right double quotation marks (U+201C & U+201D, respectively)?

Comment: Its a left and right double quotation. What actually is on that `details` column is a commendation, and it is from the client. It was quoted to indicate that those are the exact words the client mentioned.

Comment: Then they're not actually double quotes, but smart quotes. And it's a charset issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your page's charset does not match the charset of the database.

You can change your page's charset in the header section, like so:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

or you can [change the MySQL charset in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php).

Comment: I'm sorry but my charset is in that settings already